# Range of values in set statement in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hiveql

Is it possible to enter a range of values in the set statement in Hive:

eg:
PROC FORMAT;

VALUE $ABCD

'3000',

'3001',

'8816' - '8820',

'1517' - '1599' = 'Y'

OTHER = 'N';

I need this format statement in SAS to be converted and I have entered the values in set statement of Hive so I can use the 'ABCD' value in a case statement later. I am unable to find a way out to write out the range of values.

I cannot just list them out since they are not necessarily whole numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not just a syntax translation.
If you are working with SQL, you have to think SQL.

It seems you are looking for something similar to -

```
case 
    when   mycol in (3000, 3001)
        or mycol between 8816 and 8820
        or mycol between 1517 and 1599
    then 'Y'
    else 'N'
end
```

Comment: The problem is my case statement is a bit more complicated. So I am unable to use the between clause directly.

CASE 
 WHEN mycol in ('{$hiveconf:ABCD}') THEN 'XYZ'

Comment: I don't understand the issue.

Comment: There are multiple conditions that I am using within a single WHEN... clause  in the CASE statement and because of that I am unable to use between operator.

Comment: I also use multiple conditions in my answer. I see no issue here.